# org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not initialize proxy [Order#orderdate] - no Session;

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

My spring boot v2.5.5 application has master slave mysql db configured.

Primary Data Source Config

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "com.dummy",
        excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(ReadOnlyRepository.class),
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "primaryEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "primaryTransactionManager"
)
@Configuration
public class PrimaryDataSourceConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Value("${master.jdbc.url}")
    private String jdbcURL;


    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DataSource primaryDataSource() throws Exception {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create()
                .driverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
                .url(jdbcURL)
                .username("root")
                .password("root").build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean primaryEntityManagerFactory() throws Exception {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(primaryDataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan("com.dummy");

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(false);
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());

        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public PlatformTransactionManager primaryTransactionManager() throws Exception {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(primaryEntityManagerFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    final Properties additionalProperties() {
        final Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("primary.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("primary.hibernate.dialect"));
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", env.getProperty( "primary.hibernate.show_sql"));
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", "false");
        return hibernateProperties;
    }
}
```

Slave Datasource Config

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "com.dummy.submodule",
        includeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(ReadOnlyRepository.class),
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "readOnlyEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "readOnlyTransactionManager"
)
public class ReadOnlyDataSourceConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Value("${slave.jdbc.url}")
    private String jdbcURL;

    @Bean
    public DataSource readOnlyDataSource() throws Exception {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create()
                .driverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
                .url(jdbcURL)
                .username("root")
                .password("root").build();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean readOnlyEntityManagerFactory() throws Exception {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(readOnlyDataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan("com.dummy.submodule");

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(false);
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());

        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager readOnlyTransactionManager() throws Exception {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(readOnlyEntityManagerFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    final Properties additionalProperties() {
        final Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("readonly.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("readonly.hibernate.dialect"));
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", env.getProperty( "readonly.hibernate.show_sql"));
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", "false");
        return hibernateProperties;
    }
}
```

Entity

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Product implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8135071385764991866L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @NotNull
    @JoinColumn(name = "status")
    private Order order
}

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class Order implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8135071385764991879L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private Date orderdate;
}
```

I am trying to fetch Product from read only(slave) db in my service layer

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ProductService{
   private ProductRepository repo;

   public void performOperation(){
     Optional<Product> product = repo.findById(1l, Product.class);
     if(product.isPresent()){
        Order order = product.get().getOrder();
        Date orderDate = order.getOrderDate();     // this line gives below exception
     }
   }
}
```

Readonly Repository:

```
@Repository
@ReadOnlyRepository
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Long> {

    <T> Optional<T> findById(final Long id, Class<T> type);
}
```

Exception:

```
2021-10-22 12:35:11,109 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-8] com.dummy.logging.LoggingClass:41  Exception_Occurred::{}
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not initialize proxy [com.dummy.submodule.entities.Order#orderdate] - no Session; nested exception is org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy [com.dummy.submodule.entities.Order#orderdate] - no Session
```

**Note:** The LazyInitializationException occurs only when I am fetching Product from slave db. When same operation i am trying to perform using master db I am not getting LazyInitializationException.

This issue for now i have handled by making Order as FetchType.EAGER.
But i am trying to find out reason behind this in case of master slave db and how to achieve it with LAZY fetch type.

Answer (score 0):

Annotate `performOperation` with `@Transactional` like below:

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ProductService{
   private ProductRepository repo;

   @Transactional
   public void performOperation(){
     Optional<Product> product = repo.findById(1l, Product.class);
     if(product.isPresent()){
        Order order = product.get().getOrder();
        Date orderDate = order.getOrderDate();     // this line gives below exception
     }
   }
}
```